# awk: how to match two files and get the output merging these files

Tags: awk, match

I have the next problem, I have a two files with 10 col each one and different number of rows. I want to compare col 7 and if there is a match, export the complete row of both files in a different one. I'm trying

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$7]=$0;next}!a[$7]' file1  file2 > output
```

but I only get the match for file1 in other file. I don't mind if I only get the col 10 in file 1 when there is a match. Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post an example of what you trying and your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both files have at least 7 columns, you forgot to tell awk to print out both values.  Your current solution is checking if the 7th value from file2 is NOT in the array with file1 values and so will only print those lines from file2 into the new file.  So simply test value is in the array and then place a print into some curly braces:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$7]=$0;next}$7 in a{print a[$7],$0}' file1  file2 > output
```